# Usings variables within FTP

Tags: ftp

I saw a similar thread while surfing around, but didn't really get the solution. Could someone explain to me whether it would be possible (and how to do so) for me to use variables from a script in `FTP`.

Say I have a script that has variables like `$ymd` and `$pkp`, which were defined earlier and these variables were used to create a particular file name (ymd= year month date in a particular format, pkp = packing place). How do I use these variables in FTP mode?

E.g. $ymd = 20111220   $pkp = HM2
therefore, filename = 20111220HM2.data

What I'd like to do is something like this :-

ftp

open 10.123.456.78

put $pkp$ymd.data

bye

Thanks for all the help!

***Working script:***

HOST='10.123.456.78'

USER='abcd'

PASSWORD='efgh'

FILE1=''"$pkp"''"$ymd"'.data'

ftp -nvu <<
END_OF_SCRIPT

open $HOST

quote USER $USER

quote PASS $PASS

put $FILE1

bye

END_OF_SCRIPT

Comment: Any language preference? And is this going to run on a Linux or Windows machine?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. Its on a Linux

Answer (score 1):

You also didn't specify which language you're using, but basically you can create a script from bash, like so:

```
export ymd=20111220
export pkp=HM2
echo "put $pkp$ymd.data" > /tmp/ftp.tmp
echo "bye" >> /tmp/ftp.tmp
```

and then use the file `/tmp/ftp.tmp` as input to your FTP session.

Comment: Mind if I ask what exactly am I suppose to do with the .tmp file? As in...how do I use it as an input to an FTP session?

Comment: You just pass it as input to your FTP program, as per Nonym's link below:

ftp server < /tmp/ftp.tmp

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have managed to get the script working using the edited code. Cheers to all

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a Bash script for this situation. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Set variables here, or take them as arguments for your script
CURDATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
TAG="HM2"

## Actual action
ftp example.com
put $CURDATE$TAG.data
bye
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: I was using the method you suggested above. It didn't work.


ftp> put $pkp$ymd.data

local:$pkp$ymd.data: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you are using a single script or multiple scripts.

---If defining a variable in one script and then opening the ftp session in a second script you should export the variable in the first script 
(export file=names.txt).
---If you are defining the variable and opening the ftp session in the same script you don't need to export the variable 
(file=names.txt).

I use a cgi script to define and export variables and a bash script to open a vsftpd session using the variables. Or I can define and open a session in a single script without using export.

ftp -niv $HOST << ftpSession
user $USER $PASSWORD
binary
get $file
bye
ftpSession